# Conditional Formatting in GSheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet tracking activity scores for players across multiple accounts in a game I play.

I am trying to format the scores so that the monthly cells (Columns I through T) will be red if the number for the month is less than the minimum required (column B), however, nothing I have tried seems to work from other similar questions I have looked at.

I tried a simple `=I2<B2` but that ignored the 0 cells, which could be because they are results of a function which returns 0 if `vlookup` returns an error?

Using the `Less than` option in the drop down returns ever weirder results with only 2 of the cells not being red, both of which should actually be red...

I'm learning as I go so any advice would be appreciated!

[image: Data Sheet]

[image: Basic Less than formatting]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Absolutely

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqhKTN-MmWuZCLXUsiK1X8lCI-yKHrR2wWij1wGFgXI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- select cell **I2**
- set conditional format rules as:

[image]
[image]

...not sure which one you need:

**`=IF(I2>$B2,TRUE,FALSE)`**

or

**`=IF(I2<$B2,TRUE,FALSE)`**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UqhKTN-MmWuZCLXUsiK1X8lCI-yKHrR2wWij1wGFgXI/edit#gid=811926649)**